# Spring boot app using Grails GSP boot plugin Servlet/Configuration issues

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, spring-boot, gsp

I'm trying to convert a Grails 2 app into a couple of Spring Boot apps, with the re-use for now with all the GSPs. Nice boot plugin created by Lari Hotari & Graeme Rocher

https://github.com/grails/grails-boot

I'm trying to see a way that I can use content negoeation I followed a useful spring blog on the topic and I've been looking into the `GspAutoConfiguration` [See link for more info](https://github.com/grails/grails-boot/blob/master/grails-gsp-spring-boot/src/main/groovy/grails/gsp/boot/GspAutoConfiguration.java)

Doesn't appear to be a simple way that I can see to still use the GSP Template Engine from the GSP configuration to confgure content negotiation in the `MvcConfig` in the `configureContentNegotiation` bean

**Gradle.build**

```
def grailsVersion = '2.4.4'
compile "org.grails:grails-gsp-spring-boot:1.0.0"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-gsp:$grailsVersion"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:$grailsVersion"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-jsp:$grailsVersion"
compile("javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1")

//ensures that the embedded servlet container doesn’t interfere with the servlet container to which the war file will be deployed
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.3.RELEASE'   
(snipped ...)
```

**Spring MVC Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    (snippet...)

    @Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false)
            .favorParameter(true)
            .parameterName("format")
            .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
            .useJaf(false)
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
}


/**
 * Create the CNVR.  Specify the view resolvers to use explicitly.  Get Spring to inject
 * the ContentNegotiationManager created by the configurer (see previous method).
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    // Define the view resolvers
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

    //NOT this simple due to the way GspAutoConfiguration ovverrides so much view based behaviour 
    InternalResourceViewResolver r2 = new InternalResourceViewResolver()
    r2.setPrefix("/templates/views")
    r2.setSuffix(".gsp")
    resolvers.add(r2)

    JsonViewResolver r1 = new JsonViewResolver()
    resolvers.add(r1)

    // Create the CNVR plugging in the resolvers and the content-negotiation manager
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    return resolver;
}
}
```